# unescaped newline inside substitute pattern using sed?

Tags: sed

I am running the following code in MacOS with Zsh installed:

```
FILES="
DEMO04Q2.TXT DEMO04Q3.TXT DEMO04Q4.TXT
DEMO05Q1.TXT DEMO05Q2.TXT
"
for f in $FILES
do
        thefilenamenosuffix=$(basename $f .TXT)
        # remove windows carriage return,fix bad data records with embedded \n, remove the header line and add the filename as the last column on each line
        sed 's/\r$//' $f | sed 'N;s/\n\$/\$/' | sed '1,1d' | sed "1,$ s/$/$f/" >> all_version_A_demo_legacy_data_with_filename.txt
done
```

results in:

sed:
DEMO04Q2.TXT DEMO04Q3.TXT DEMO04Q4.TXT
DEMO05Q1.TXT DEMO05Q2.TXT
: No such file or directory
sed: 1: "1,$ s/$/
DEMO04Q2.TXT D ...": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern

All files are in the same directory as the same script. I am probably missing something simple.

I verified that the files were in the same directory as the script I was running.

Answer (score 0):

Can't resolve all you want to do but will just discect the sed expressions.

Not sure of the root causes but found two issues in your expression(s), one yours one zsh (??mac?) but both are wrt the '$' char:

1 - basic structure:

```
    sed 's/\r$//' $f | sed 'N;s/\n\$/\$/' | sed '1,1d' | sed "1,$ s/$/$f/"
```

better format to see/understand what's happening:

```
    sed -e 's/\r$//' \
        -e 's/\n\$/\$/' \      <<< 'N' not needed, ?? what doing?
        -e '1,1d' \            <<< this seems to be first
        -e "1,$ s/$/$f/"  $f   <<< see #2 mext
```

2 - issues with quoted (") '$' used to indicate end of line in sed: seems the shell is trying to interpret it.

I am just transitioning from ksh to zsh and ran into it.

Better folks than I can explain the root problem.

My solution was keeping it in single quotes:

```
    "s/$/$f/" => "s/"'$'"/$f/"
```

NOTE: you could just double quote the last segment but my scripts were much more complicated and it was simpler to just single quote the EOL '$' char.